# Queuing system concurrency problems with relational database

Tags: node.js, concurrency, queue, hana, database-deadlocks

Hi everyone I'm developing a nodejs script to manage jobs.
I have a function that launches the following transaction:

```
    const globalTask = () => {
      await startTransaction();
      const job = await sql(`SELECT * FROM "jobs" WHERE "state"='WAITING' LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE 
                             IGNORE LOCKED`);
      if (job) {
           await sql(`UPDATE "jobs" SET "state"='PENDING' WHERE "id"=${job[0].id}`);
      }
      await this.commit();
      if (!job) return;
      
      // other phases...
      // here the job is processed....
   };
```

Then I have a "main" function that with a Promise.all launches 10 times the globalTask() function.
Unfortunately, sometimes I get an exception with the message "transaction rolled back by detected deadlock: TrexColumnUpdate failed on table" jobs "or I notice that one or more row has been chosen several times.
How should I change the sql command?
The database I use is SAP HANA.

```
const main = async () => {
    const results = await Promise.all([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].map(_ => globalTask())); 

   // business logic
};
```

Comment: Concurrency based deadlocks are a little more of a theory than a here's an actual answer,as it depends on what you want to do.  Like, you could detect the deadlock error, then decide to try and read from the table again with a `NOT IN` clause in your SQL building up x amount of times till you have a readable/writeable job id.

Comment: This issue requires more detail information, I.e. the deadlock trace information to understand which transactions were involved in what way. I recommend opening a support incident to have this analysed.